# If the cells had numbers like cell E = '4' and cell F = '5', how would you determine which one is greater

Tags: java, excel

```
public class Read {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    File f = new File ("/users/Me/Documents/Test.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
    int row = s.getRows();
    int col = s.getColumns();
    //for(int i = 0; i<row;i++){
    //for(int j = 0; j<col;j++){
        Cell c = s.getCell(4,1);
        Cell e = s.getCell(5,1);
         System.out.print(c.getContents()+"\t");
        System.out.print(e.getContents()+"\t");

   // }
//}
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

I tried this if statement if(c.getContents()>e.getContents()...but I am getting errors.

Comment: Isn't this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009462/how-do-i-modify-the-code-so-it-only-prints-cells-e-and-f/30009503#30009503 ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to write

```
if(Double.parseDouble(c.getContents())>Double.parseDouble(e.getContents())) {...}
```

This should work if you sure that these cells contain numbers. Otherwise it would be reasonable to theck c.getType()/e.getType() first.